# wxPython SetFocus() not working

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to use SetFocus() on a window in wxPython.  I'm not sure exactly what it should look like on Mac, but as far as I can tell there are no visual changes at all when I call window.SetFocus(), and window.HasFocus() returns False.  Here's some simplified example code:

```
app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, '')
box = wx.StaticBox(frame, -1, "")
sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box, orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
text = wx.StaticText(frame, label="Some Text")
sizer.Add(text, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, border=10)
main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
main_sizer.Add(sizer)
frame.SetSizer(main_sizer)

frame.Centre()
frame.Show()
text.SetFocus()
print 'text.HasFocus?', text.HasFocus()

app.MainLoop()
```

This problem is present with wxPython versions '2.9.2.4' and '3.0.2.0'.  Any ideas?

edit:

It looks like a StaticText widget cannot accept focus (window.AcceptFocus()) returns False).  In that case, is there a simple, accepted way of highlighting a window like this?  Or, is it possible to change whether or not a window can accept focus?

Comment: What I'm really looking for is a standard way to draw a large, colored border around an arbitrary widget.  Most often, I will want a border around buttons, but SetDefault won't work because I want to highlight more than one at a time.  If I use SetBackgroundColour, it creates a very thin highlight - not enough to draw attention to the widget.  Is there a general approach for this kind of end goal?

Comment: @J Jones That is an entirely different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is static text arguably there is nothing to receive focus as you cannot click into it.
Try your code amended slightly to see how to set focus and use event.focus to see changes in focus.

```
import wx
def onFocus(event):
    print "widget received focus!"

def onKillFocus(event):
    print "widget lost focus!"

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, '')
box = wx.StaticBox(frame, -1, "")
sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box, orient=wx.VERTICAL)
text0 = wx.StaticText(frame,label="1st Item")
text0_input = wx.TextCtrl(frame, wx.ID_ANY, size=(345,25))
text = wx.StaticText(frame, label="Some Text")
text_input = wx.TextCtrl(frame, wx.ID_ANY, size=(345,25))
sizer.Add(text0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, border=10)
sizer.Add(text0_input, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, border=10)
sizer.Add(text, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, border=10)
sizer.Add(text_input, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, border=10)
text0_input.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, onFocus)
text0_input.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, onKillFocus)

main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
main_sizer.Add(sizer)
frame.SetSizer(main_sizer)

frame.Centre()
frame.Show()
text_input.SetFocus()
#print 'text_input.HasFocus?', text_input.HasFocus()

app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wx.StaticText` widget does not accept focus. If you are just trying to bring your window to the front, you can probably use the frame's `Raise` method. Most other widgets do allow you to set the focus on them so you can edit them.

If you want to highlight some text in a `wx.StaticText` widget, you might try changing its background color. This should work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the second question posed in your comment.
I'm not sure what you are referring to when you say that setting the background colour creates a very thin highlight.
You can draw attention to buttons which are relevant or not at any given moment by enabling or disabling them. You can also change their colour depending on whether they are enabled, disabled or on a whim really.

For example:

```
        self.button.Disable()
        self.button.SetBackgroundColour(wx.NullColour)

        self.button.Enable()
        self.button.SetBackgroundColour('gold')
```

Setting the background colour should change the colour of the entire button.
You could also change the foreground colour which would change the colour of the text on any given button.